# How can I get a percentage of the use of all active applications from Ram by Phonegap , Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ram

How can I get a percentage of the use of all active applications from Ram by Phonegap , Cordova ?

For Android , ios

Help me .

Answer (score 0):

There is no available plugin to use for this operation right now. If you check the cordova [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/index.html) you will see all the rest plugins that you can use.

Comment: Thank you
Can I know the number of active applications by phonegap, cordova?

Comment: I don't think that's possible too. Sorry.